# Cannot read property of undefined $cordovaSocialSharing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using the cordovaSocialSharing-plugin like this in my controller :

```
 app.controller('eventDetailCtrl',function($scope, $cordovaSocialSharing){
     $scope.shareEvent = function(){
         $cordovaSocialSharing.share('This is my message', 'Subject string', null, 'http://www.mylink.com');
     }
  })
```

But following error message appears in the console: `Cannot read property   'socialsharing' of undefined`.

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following:

1. The plugin is added to your project by running the following from CLI:

> cordova plugin add
>   https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

2. You are testing the plugin in device or emulator, most Cordova plugins are not available in browser.